# MySql : How can i split the string on single "\" backslash

Tags: mysql, string, split, backslash

Can anyone please share the syntax to split the string on single "\" backslash. The string is of the form "abc\xyz" and i want to extract the "xyz" from the string. I tried using substring_index(), position() and locate() but all are throwing syntax error if i try to use single backslash and returning the whole string if I use "\".

Comment: *I tried using substring_index()* Show the code you have tried.

Comment: SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX("abc\xyz", "\", -1) : this is throwing syntax error and If I use double backslash "\\" returns the whole string "abcxyz"

Answer (score 1):

For Column, you can use the following query

```
SELECT Substring_Index(Column,'\\',-1) FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

if you are planning on just a single string, then

```
SELECT Substring_Index('abc\\xyz','\\',-1) FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

the '\' needs to be escaped with '\\'

if you try the following query

```
SELECT ("abc\\xyz"); or SELECT ('abc\\xyz');
```

the output is:
    abc\xyz

Let me know if it works for you